# How to restrict admin page via URL?

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, authorization

I am building a website wherein I have an admin and user page. I have a problem wherein I can access the admin page via URL even though I am logged in as a user. I have validation checks at the login page, however if I am already logged in as a user or as an admin, I can access all the pages. I want to restrict the pages to their roles only.

This is my controller

```
class login extends CI_Controller
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url','html');
        $this->load->model('login_model');
     
    
    }
    public function index(){
        $this->load->view('login');
    }
    public function verify_login()
    {
        $data = $this->login_model->verify_login();
        if ($data) {
            $userdata = array('id' => $data[0]['user_id'] , 'name' => $data[0]['full_name'], 'type' => $data[0]['user_type'] );
            $this->session->set_userdata('login_info',$userdata);

            if($userdata['type'] == 0) {
                header("Location: ".base_url()."home");
            } 
            else {
                header("Location: ".base_url()."reports_controller");
            }
        
        }
     
        else{
            header("Location: ".base_url()."login");
        }
    }

    public function logout(){
        $this->session->sess_destroy('login_info');
        header("Location: ".base_url()."login");
    }
}
```

Comment: you forgot to attach your code

Comment: create roles based on the user types and check the role on MY_controller and extend this My_controller in other controllers. Or you can simply check the user_type and can restrict the access there.

Comment: have you checked the session login_info on other controllers in which you would want to restrict for user type?

Comment: yeah i every controller i have checked my login_info

Comment: shoma bayaad as session estefada koneen.

Comment: را session خو استفاده کرده ام

Comment: you must set the role of the user as a session.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to check what your session value will return,then you can restrict url.Use this to check your session 
$session = $this->session->userdata('login_info');
$type = $session['type'];

Comment: here is not the problem it cant take the the id of the user as a value

Comment: mean you have to check id not type?